# Powershell and logparser arguments in herestring not working

Tags: csv, powershell, logparser

I'm trying to pass som logparserarguments from powershell, just because i need to get the date right to be able to get the right data at the right time. 
But logparser wont accept the code from powershell, but if i run it directly from cmd without the needed date variable it works.

```
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%y%m%d"
$exe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe"
$herestring = @"
"SELECT 
date AS Date, 
time as Time, 
s-ip as Server-IP, 
cs-uri-stem as Request-URI 
FROM C:\Local\temp\S0000\u_ex$date*.log 
WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/%'
-i:IISW3C -o:csv -q:off >c:\Local\test\Activesynccalls1.csv
"@ 
start-process $exe -ArgumentList $herestring
```

When passing this to logparser, logparser complains about `"Error: Syntax Error: extra token(s) after query: '-i:IISW3C'`
but when i add a quotationmark after `...tiveSync/%'"`. it wont even take the argument at all, but when using the same argument in cmd it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work for several reasons:

- A herestring does not create a `string[]` which is what `-ArgumentList` wants
- The quote before the `SELECT` is superfluous.
- The redirection inside the `-ArgumentList` won't work. `Start-Process` does not start a shell `cmd` but, the process directly.

Also, you don't need `Start-Process` at all, but can directly run `LogParser.exe` (you could, but it is not necessary here).

What you could try is something like this:

```
$date = Get-Date -UFormat "%y%m%d"
$query = @"
SELECT date AS Date, time as Time, s-ip as Server-IP, cs-uri-stem as Request-URI 
FROM C:\Local\temp\S0000\u_ex$date*.log 
WHERE cs-uri-stem LIKE '%/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync/%'
"@

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\LogParser.exe" $query -i:IISW3C -o:csv -q:off > c:\Local\test\Activesynccalls1.csv
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works the way i want it :D Wich means i can also extend the query as much as i want if i need :) Thank you !!